# eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm currently using [ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol) for a smart contract and the Web3.js library in the Node.js backend server. When I try to call the [mint](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/440b65bf776f57cba7a1562caabd94ce41dfb12a/contracts/token/ERC721/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol#L69) function using this [Web3 API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send):

```js
 var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoIdABI, ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoIdContractAddress, {
    from: from, 
    gasPrice: gasPrice
  });

  let result;
  try {
    result = await myContract.methods.mint(receipientAddress).send();
    res.status(201).send(result)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(201).send(error)
  }
```

I get the following error:

> Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

I'm communicating to the Rinkeby blockchain through the Infura gateway and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164062/10116367), Infura supports only `eth_sendRawTransaction`, not `eth_sendTransaction`.

I was able to successfully send Ether using a [signed transaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction):

```js
  const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice()
  const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from, 'pending')
  var rawTx = {
      nonce: txCount,
      gasPrice:"0x" + gasPrice,
      gasLimit: '0x200000',
      to: to,
      value: "0x1000000000000000",
      data: "0x",
      chainId: 4
  };

  var privateKey = new Buffer.from(pk, "hex")
  var tx = new Tx(rawTx, {"chain": "rinkeby"});
  tx.sign(privateKey);

  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  const signedTx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"));
```

However, I'm unable to call the `mint` method on the smart contract using the raw transaction. I've tried:

```js
await myContract.methods.mint(receipientAddress).sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"));
```

or

```js
await myContract.methods.mint(receipientAddress).sendRawTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"));
```

But, I still get the error message `eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available`.

**Update**

I tried using signing the transaction using a Truffle's library on the advise of @MikkoOhtamaa:

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const privateKeys = process.env.PRIVATE_KEYS || ""
const walletAPIUrl = `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  privateKeys.split(','),
  walletAPIUrl
);
const web3 = new Web3API(provider)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a Web3.js middleware layer that signs transactions locally, instead of sending a JSON-RPC method to Infura.

One of the solutions is [Truffle HDWallet](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider).

Comment: I updated the question, but what I'm confused about is, am I getting the private key dynamically from the user to configure the `HDWallet`? Also, should I be using the JSON-RPC method alongside with `HDWallet` because there are some Web3 functionalities like creating a wallet that you have to use without a private key? I believe there is not way to configure `HDWallet` without a private key or mnemonic.

Comment: `dynamically from the user to configure` you don't. You never import user keys to the server-side. If you get private key from the user then effectively you become a hacker and all blockchain security guarantees are lost.

Comment: just to clarify, does this mean signing the transaction always has to be done in the front end and never on the server? The reason I'm asking is I would like to use the web3.js library, but I'm not using Javascript on the front end so I'm unable to do so.

Comment: `just to clarify, does this mean signing the transaction always has to be done in the front end` -> Yes

Comment: Do you guys know if there is a way to do it through a mobile app?

Comment: Here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/connecting-the-wallet-of-to-your-dapp-and-different-ethereum-wallet-types/82532#82532