# "Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist" on non-payable functions only

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I can call payable functions that mutate the state of the contract just fine. I cannot call non-payable functions that mutate the state.

The problem isn't the function, I can call it fine on Remix IDE.

```
await contract.methods.test().send({from:account}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The method eth\_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154713/error-the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass 0 to `value` parameter.

`contract.methods.test().send({from:account, value: 0})`