# The method eth_signTypedData_v4 does not exist/is not available

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

Showing an error while calling solidity contract, which is deployed already in rinkeby-infura. I am using ethers.js inside my React app. I've seen similar issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154713/error-the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available) but I am not simply trying to send a transaction but rather trying to sign a type data as explained [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTypedData). And I am calling it almost the same:

```
const signature = await mySigner._signTypedData(domain, types, voucher)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was doing had the almost same issue as the [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154713/error-the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available) I provided. I was trying to sign a typed data. This used to be working in my Hardhat project and from what I understand the hardhat was interrupting the call and using my private key which was provided inside the hardhat.config.js file. How do I resolve this issue?

Instead of using regular JSONRpcProvider, I started using injectedProvider. I've found an example here: https://docs.scaffoldeth.io/scaffold-eth/examples-branches/common-web3-patterns/signator.io

The injectedProvider was also present inside the example project that I am using ([here](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/nft-school-examples/tree/main/end-to-end)). But for some reason it was exist inside the [App.jsx](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/nft-school-examples/blob/main/end-to-end/packages/react-app/src/App.jsx) but never send (or used) to the [Minter.jsx](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/nft-school-examples/blob/main/end-to-end/packages/react-app/src/components/Minter.jsx). I've added the injectedProvider to the `mintNFT` class and get the signer from there with `const mySigner = injectedProvider.getSigner()`. After that I was able to successfully sign the typed data with await `mySigner._signTypedData(domain, types, voucher)`. This opened a nice pop-up in my MetaMask wallet and I signed the message.