# Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: javascript, transactions, solidity, metamask

I've deployed a smart contract which works well, however if I try to interact with the function sendToOwner():

```
.sol
function sendToOwner() public onlyOwner {
    require(
        address(this).balance - gasleft() * tx.gasprice > gasleft() * tx.gasprice,
        "Contract balance is not enough to pay for gas"
    );

    payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

```
react.js
async function getCrypto(contractAddress) {
    try {
        if (contractAddress !== '') {
            const infuraURL = "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/" + INFURA_ID;
            const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(infuraURL));

            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT.abi, contractAddress);

            await contract.methods.sendToOwner().send(
            { from: currentAccount.address, gas: 300000 });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available.

After conducting research, I realized that it is necessary to sign transactions, but due to my inexperience, I cannot imagine how this can be implemented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The method eth\_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154713/error-the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available)

Answer (score 2):

[eth_sendTransaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction) signs the transaction on the node - meaning the node needs to hold the private key to the sender address. Most 3rd party node providers disable this method since they don't hold any private keys on their nodes.

The [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) library sends an **unsigned transaction** object to the `eth_sendTransaction` method - and a **signed and serialized** transaction to the [eth_sendRawTransaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendrawtransaction) method. *(The same logic applies to [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers) and other libraries.)*

In order to sign and serialize the transaction in your app, you need to pass the private key to your web3 instance. You can do that using the [wallet.add()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add) method.

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0xprivateKey");

// now web3 sends the transaction using the `eth_sendRawTransaction` method
await contract.methods.sendToOwner().send(
    { from: currentAccount.address, gas: 300000 }
);
```

This approach is commonly used in backend apps where you know the private key and can securely pass it to the `web3` instance.

---

In frontend apps, the signing and broadcasting is usually handled by wallet software such as MetaMask. The wallet usually opens up a popup asking the user to confirm the transaction - and when the user confirms, the wallet sings and serializes the transaction, and broadcasts it using its configured RPC node.

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

// the app doesn't know the private key
// the signing & broadcasting is handled by the wallet
await contract.methods.sendToOwner().send(
    { from: currentAccount.address, gas: 300000 }
);
```

Comment: thank you very much, by connecting through the `window.ethereum` I was able to send the transaction.